# WIA Scanning issues on XP

Tags: c#, wpf, wia

I have a WPF application that I am using to scan documents to a users mailbox etc.

When debugging the application on my 32bit Windows 7 professional machine all goes according to plan, as well as the deployed version on another 32bit Windows 7 machine.

When I deploy to a XP machine and try to start a scan I get the following error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {850D1D11-70F3-4BE5-9A11-77AA6B2BB201} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you registered the wiaaut.dll file on the target machine?

Comment: When registering the DLL with regsvr32 i get the following error: "LoadLibrary('E:\windows\system32\wiaaut.dll') failed - The specified procedure could not be found". Note that the DLL was copied from my development PC.

Comment: I had the same issue - the win7 version will not work on xp, unfortunatley i couldnt find it anywhere online all the links to it were broken - i managed to find an xp machine with it on and copied it from that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The win 7 version does not work on xp - you could try downloading this version for XP.

[download here](http://vbnet.mvps.org/files/updates/wiaautsdk.zip)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could not find this dll anywhere and all MS links are down.

Comment: so should I use  wiaaut.dll instead of Interop.WIA.dll?

Answer (score 0):

To make deployment simpler, turn the files from Richard Friend's Answer into an Inno installer.

```
[Setup]
AppId={{4D9ADCF1-F6B4-4790-8B21-3C9F93346638}}
AppName="Microsoft Windows XP x86 WIA 2.0 Installer"
AppVersion="2.0"

OutputBaseFilename="Microsoft Windows XP x86 WIA 2.0 Installer"
Compression=lzma2/ultra64
CreateAppDir=no
Uninstallable=no

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Files]
Source: Files\wiaaut.chi; DestDir: {win}\HELP; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist
Source: Files\wiaaut.chm; DestDir: {win}\HELP; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist 
Source: Files\wiaaut.dll; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist regserver
```

I just did that since I have to deploy this in a small office and it works. I'm putting it on x86 machines only. You might have to tweak it a bit to work on x64 machines.