# WPF App with WIA not being installed on client

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-xp, wia

I've developed a WPF application with .net 4.0 that it's using the WIA Library.

I've referenced the dll of the XP version because my system need to run on Win XP and above... Everything goes fine on my development machine, but I can't make it work anywhere else.

For the installation I'am using the Express Edition, in the files that will go with the solution, i've added all the files from my "Release" folder of the Project, because i can't make it work with the output of the project... And i've added the wiaaut.dll too...

On the client I've installed the app and registered the dll with regsvr32.exe... but it doesn't work... On a Win8 clean machine and on XP I receive an error when I try to initialize the object from the scanner, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793576/wia-scanning-issues-on-xp) error...

Am I missing anything else to make it work? When i test it in another dev machine it works normal too...

PS. My dev machine is a Win 8 with VS 2010.

Comment: You cannot copy system DLLs like wiaaut.dll and expect them to work on another machine.  Wrong version, most of all, but it is just one file from the set that implement WIA.  There used to be a download from Microsoft that back-ported WIA 2.0 to XP.  That download is no longer available.  XP is dead.

Comment: I wish it was really dead man, but it is not here in Brazil, a lot of companys still use it. I've found here on stackoverflow a link to the WIA for XP, it has just the dll and some samples actually